# Eager loading via QueryBuilder leftJoin

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

When I wrote:

```php
$query = $this->employeeRepository->createQueryBuilder('e')
    ->leftJoin('e.department', 'd')
;
return $query->getQuery()->getResult();
```

I expected to get the related eagerly but got Proxy instead.
[image: isInitialized false Doctrine proxy]

Is there a way to force Doctrine to that relation eagerly `without modifying the annotations` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to select the value too, like:

```
$query = $this->employeeRepository->createQueryBuilder('e')
    ->select("e", "d")
    ->leftJoin('e.department', 'd')
;
```

Comment: It didn't work I was getting. **[Semantical Error] line 0, col -1 near 'SELECT d FROM': Error: Cannot select entity through identification variables without choosing at least one root entity alias.** after I've set **->select("e", "d")** it started working properly.

Comment: Update your post and I will mark it as correct answer. :) Thanks

Comment: Indeed, thx for the feedback @sebastian_t